Auto Rotation support & other tablet stuff
I have a HP tablet, that ran Windows, which now runs Ubuntu; It works pretty fine, except for volume buttons, camera and auto rotation, which makes me feel, like im running a computer with missing stuff; But i want the tablet to be a tablet, that supports tablet stuff.
Are there any at least auto-rotation drivers for the tablet? At least generic/universal drivers?

My system details:
Hardware Information:

Hardware Model:                              HP HP Elite x2 1012 G2
Memory:                                      16.0 GiB
Processor:                                   Intel® Core™ i5-7300U × 4
Graphics:                                    Intel® HD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2)
Disk Capacity:                               256.1 GB

Software Information:

Firmware Version:                            P87 Ver. 01.49
OS Name:                                     Ubuntu 24.10
OS Build:                                    (null)
OS Type:                                     64-bit
GNOME Version:                               47
Windowing System:                            Wayland
Kernel Version:                              Linux 6.11.0-13-generic


and also fingerprint, if possible

i would have the same issue on windows, if i don‘t use windows update w/ intel driver stuff, would‘ve been cool if there‘s something similar. and yeah, i don‘t use windows, because somehow, the brightness and wifi stops working and the service would just disappear from Services; i like to be free!
